# Issue with CSS when generating HTML using jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

When I generate my HTML using jquery the css doesn't load and leaves me an awful display.

Here is the code that generates the HTML :

```
function createHtml(type,idx,name,data)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case 'Temp + Humidity':
            var data = data.split(", ");
            $("#data").append('<li id="'+idx+'"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p style="color:coral;">' + data[0] + '</p><p style="color:lightblue;">' + data[1] + '</p></li>');
            break;

        case 'Wind':
            var data = data.split(";");
            $("#data").append('<li id="' + idx + '"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p>Direction :' + data[1] + ' Speed : ' + data[2] + '</p></li>');
            break;

        case 'Rain':
            $("#data").append('<li id="' + idx + '"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p>' + data + 'ml</p></li>');
            break;

        case 'General':
            $("#data").append('<li id="' + idx + '"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p>' + data + '</p></li>');
            break;

        case 'Thermostat':
            $("#data").append('<li id="' + idx + '"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p>' + data + '°C</p><div class="ui-btn-right" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-notext" onclick="tempSetMinus(this.id)" id="' + idx + 'Minus">Minus Icon</a><a class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext" onclick="tempSetPlus(this.id)" id="' + idx + 'Plus">Plus Icon</a></div></li>');
            break;

        case 'Air Quality':
            $("#data").append('<li id="' + idx + '"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p>' + data + '</p></li>');
            break;
        case 'Lux':
            $("#data").append('<li id="' + idx + '"><h2>' + name + ' :</h2><p>' + data + '</p></li>');
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

And what I want:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with your problem?

Comment: No, I can't because there isn't jquery-mobile with jsfiddle

Comment: `$( "#data" ).listview( "refresh" );` http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh

Comment: @saroten, you can manually add any external JS file / CSS you like by adding it in the left-hand pane. I've added it to this fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ss5jbcu9/